# What causes synaptic impairment?

Tags: neocron

I have noticed while playing that occasionally I get synaptic impairment. I notice this normally after using the gene-replicator. What causes synaptic impairment and is there a way to avoid it?

[image: Skills window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synaptic impairment as shown on the skills window is a percentage based reduction of your abilities caused by "a shock to the system" while playing.

You get synaptic impairment from the following sources:

- Using a gene-replicator gives you 19% synaptic impairment
- Dying and releasing gives you 42% synaptic impairment
- As a droner, if one of your drones is destroyed, you will get 4% synaptic impairment

Synaptic impairment stacks, so if you die multiple times in quick succession you can get upto 100% synaptic impairment. Synaptic impairment wears off by 2% every 15 seconds.